# Powershell handling null value

Tags: powershell

Hello my script is returning a null value error on the following line 
"Size MB over 180 days old" = $MbxSearch.ResultItemsSize.Value.ToMB()
as some users do not have messages in their mailbox which meet the following search query
AND Received: < $('01/03/2014 23:59:59')

How can I handle the "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" error within the array / hash table.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Here is my script

```
$Results = @()
$MailboxUser = Get-Content D:\Mike_X\Import\MbxUsers.txt
$MailboxUser | ForEach {
$Mailbox = Get-Mailbox $_
$MbxStatsArchive = Get-MailboxStatistics -Archive $_
$MbxStats = Get-MailboxStatistics $_
$MbxSearch = Search-Mailbox -DoNotIncludeArchive -SearchQuery "Received: >     $('01/01/1980 00:00:00') AND Received: < $('01/03/2014 23:59:59')" -EstimateResultOnly $_

    $Properties = @{
    "Live Mailbox Name" = $Mailbox.DisplayName
    "Archive Mailbox Name" = $MbxStatsArchive.DisplayName
    "Archive Quota GB" = $Mailbox.ArchiveQuota.Value.ToGB()
    "Archive Size MB" = $MbxStatsArchive.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()
    "Archive Database" = $MbxStatsArchive.Database
    "Live Mailbox Size MB" = $MbxStats.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()
    "Items over 180 days old" = $MbxSearch.ResultItemsCount
    "Size MB over 180 days old" = $MbxSearch.ResultItemsSize.Value.ToMB()           

}

$Results += New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties

}

$Results | Select-Object "Live Mailbox Name","Live Mailbox Size MB","Archive Mailbox  Name","Archive Quota GB","Archive Size MB",`
"Archive Database","Items over 180 days old","Size MB over 180 days old" | FL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test it before you construct the HashTable and assign the value to a temporary variable:

```
$SizeMB = 0
if($MbxSearch.ResultItemsSize.Value -ne $null)
{
    $SizeMB = $MbxSearch.ResultItemsSize.Value.ToMB()
}
$Properties = @{
    "Live Mailbox Name" = $Mailbox.DisplayName
    "Archive Mailbox Name" = $MbxStatsArchive.DisplayName
    "Archive Quota GB" = $Mailbox.ArchiveQuota.Value.ToGB()
    "Archive Size MB" = $MbxStatsArchive.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()
    "Archive Database" = $MbxStatsArchive.Database
    "Live Mailbox Size MB" = $MbxStats.TotalItemSize.Value.ToMB()
    "Items over 180 days old" = $MbxSearch.ResultItemsCount
    "Size MB over 180 days old" = $SizeMB
}
```